# simplexml load on google weather api prooblem

Tags: php, simplexml

Hi I have been having problems with the google weather api having errors Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 2: parser error ....

I tried to use the script of the main author(thinking it was my edited script) but still I am having this errors I tried 2 
//komunitasweb.com/2009/09/showing-the-weather-with-php-and-google-weather-api/

and

//tips4php.net/2010/07/local-weather-with-php-and-google-weather/

The weird part is sometimes it fixes itself then goes back again to the error I have been using it for months now without any problem, this just happened yesterday. Also the demo page of the authors are working but I have the same exact code any help please.

this is my site http://j2sdesign.com/weather/widgetlive1.php

@Mike I added your code

```
<?
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=jakarta');  if (!     simplexml_load_string($xml)) {   file_put_contents('malformed.xml', $xml); }
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=jakarta');
$information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
$current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
$forecast_list = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");
```

?>

and made a list of the error but I can't seem to see the error cause it's been fixing itself then after sometime goes back again to the error

here is the content of the file

```
<?php  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');  // create doctype $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");  
// display document in browser as plain text 
// for readability purposes //header("Content-Type: text/plain");  
// create root element 
$xmlProducts = $dom->createElement("products"); 
$dom->appendChild($xmlProducts);  
$pages = array(     'http://myshop.com/small_houses.html',     'http://myshop.com/medium_houses.html',     'http://myshop.com/large_houses.html' )   foreach($pages as $page) {     $product = array();     $source = file_get_html($page);      foreach($source->find('img') as $src)     {         if (strpos($src->src,"http://myshop.com") === false)         {             $product['image'] = "http://myshop.com/$src->src";         }     }      foreach($source->find('p[class*=imAlign_left]') as $description)     {         $product['description'] =  $description->innertext;     }      foreach($source->find('span[class*=fc3]') as $title)     {         $product['title'] =  $title->innertext;     }      //debug perposes!      echo "Current Page: " . $page . "\n";     print_r($product);     echo "\n\n\n"; //Clear seperator } ?>
```

Comment: ok now it's working hopefully it stays that way

Comment: The error is back again please help thanks

Comment: even this one doesn't work //www.ankitsharma.info/blog/weather-widget-using-google-weather-api I am using the authors script http://j2sdesign.com/wg/wg/weatherg/documentation-and-example/ is this a problem with my hosting?

Comment: @cooldude The last error should exist in malformed.xml. Can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: now it's working again, it fixed itself this is really weird

Comment: Lots of people put effort into helping you out.  Deleting this question would result in them losing rep.  If your issue is solved by some other means, leave an answer with your solution and select it when the option becomes available.  Helps people who have similar issues and doesn't penalize those that tried to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `simplexml_load_string()` fails you need to store the data you're trying to load somewhere for review. Examining the data is the first step to diagnose what it causing the error.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.xml');

if (!simplexml_load_string($xml)) {
  file_put_contents('malformed.xml', $xml);
}
```

Comment: @Mike: +1. The error is being thrown because the XML being returned is not valid.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your reply I'm just wondering why it is working on the authors page not on mine I just copied that exact script he posted is this a problem with my hosting?

Comment: @cooldude We can't answer that until we found out what the problem is.

Comment: if you guys have free time on your hand can you do me a favor and just try the code from komunista or the other one I sent tips4php it's a simple cut and paste i would really appreciate it just to see if the problem is in my hosting

Comment: Seems it's not only on my hosting I googled the warning string and lots of site came up ex. //www.jardineriechatou.fr/ you would see the error on the rail

Comment: i also added wp google weather plugin on my wordpress test page same result with warning problems here is my site j2sdesign.com/blog/